# Psych Package - Extract factor scores from fa.poly function

Tags: r

I used `fa.poly` function for factor analysis of categorical manifest variables. I am now trying to extract the factor scores from the results. However, the `str` function indicates that factor scores are not "stored" in the results.

This is in contrast to the factor analysis function for continuous variables - `fa` - where the scores are stored in the results and can be extracted using `results$scores`

```
results <- fa.poly(inputdata, 4, fm = "pa", rotate = "oblimin")
```

`results$scores` gives NULL

VERSUS

```
results2 <- fa(inputdata, 4, fm = "pa", rotate = "oblimin")
```

`results2$scores` gives desired results

Comment: This appears to depend on the data. There is no "scores" component in the "pa" result returned from the first example on the `fa`-help-page. There is an "r.scores" matrix in that list.

Comment: in general, when you want to extract a value from an output, have a look at `str(<output>)` to point you in the direction of where to dig.

Comment: Thanks! The new version of Psych package (1.3.10.12) resolves this issue.

Comment: Sometimes things are hidden inside printed objects.

Answer (score 7):

Please update to 1.3.10.12 which was just added to Cran this weekend.  I finally got around to allowing you to do this.

Bill

Answer (score 1):

Use the `fa` function, but add `cor="poly"` to the code to make sure it uses the polychoric correlation for ordinal variables:

```
results2 <- fa(inputdata, 4, fm = "pa", rotate = "oblimin", cor = "poly")
```